# React Native integration in existing app best practices

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, walmart-electrode

In last days I try to understand what is the best practices to integrate new features created with react native in android/ios native projects?

For now, I found these solutions:

1. Move Android and IOS native projects to the same folder. Initialise package.json file for RN and we are good to go. This solution means that we need to have a mono-repo in git. 
   The advantages that I see here is that we can integrate any third-party libraries without a problem.
2. Walmart electrode native solution. Did anyone try this solution? It looks like it can be a great solution because each feature isolated from the actual native application. But I found that it can be difficult to integrate any native third party libraries that are not supported by Walmart.

So whats the best practice to integrate RN feature (can be multiple screens with inner navigation) in Android and IOS exist projects?

Answer (score 0):

2. Walmart electrode native solution

Third party libraries can be added to the manifest repo. Walmart has some of the third party libs added to the manifest already. Please feel free to open a PR to this repo if you want to add something that's not already added. Open issues in GitHub incase you have questions.

You can read more about manifest and how to add dependencies here: [manifest-documentation](https://electrode.gitbooks.io/electrode-native/content/platform-parts/manifest.html)

Here is the manifest repo url: [electrode-native-manifest](https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-native-manifest/)